# Select all rows containing NaN until a column with value appears

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

| ValueA | Value B |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| NaN | 2 |
| NaN | 3 |
| b | 4 |
| NaN | 5 |
| NaN | 6 |
| c | 7 |
| NaN | 8 |
| NaN | 9 |

I want to create a DataFrame, in which all values between b and c are stored - including b, excluding c.

The expected output is as follows:

| ValueA | Value B |
| --- | --- |
| b | 4 |
| NaN | 5 |
| NaN | 6 |

Comment: 1, 2, 3 or 4, 5, 6?

Comment: Did you try something already? Why didn't that work as expected? What's the starting point?

Comment: @NYCCoder I´ve edited the question - sorry!

Comment: @aaossa I don't really know where to start. I know about `df.iloc[3:6]`, but that won't help me here.

Comment: does `b` and `c` occur more than once?

Comment: @Jonnyb170 Can you please clarify whether you will know in advance that "c" is the stop value, or if you only know that you are starting with "b" and that you want to stop at the next value after "b" that is not NaN?

Comment: @constantstranger I indeed don't know what c is, so I mean the latter. Your answer was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ValueA' : ['a', np.nan, np.nan, 'b', np.nan, np.nan, 'c', np.nan, np.nan],
    'Value B' : list(range(1, 10))})
print(df)

start = df[df['ValueA'] == 'b'].index.tolist()[0]
end = start + 1
while end < df.shape[0] and type(df['ValueA'].loc[end]) is not str and math.isnan(df['ValueA'].loc[end]):
    end += 1
df2 = df.loc[start:end - 1].reset_index(drop=True, inplace=False)
print(f"\n{df2}")
```

Output:

```
  ValueA  Value B
0      a        1
1    NaN        2
2    NaN        3
3      b        4
4    NaN        5
5    NaN        6
6      c        7
7    NaN        8
8    NaN        9

  ValueA  Value B
0      b        4
1    NaN        5
2    NaN        6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "default" index (composed of consecutive integers, starting from 0),
then one of possible solutions is to find indices of the "wanted" rows:

```
ind1, ind2 = df.index[df['ValueA'].isin(['b', 'c'])].tolist()
```

Then just retrieve rows from this range (excluding the right border):

```
result = df[ind1:ind2]
```

The result is:

```
  ValueA  Value B
3      b        4
4    NaN        5
5    NaN        6
```

This code will work also if both "border" values are not in lexicographic
order. Values of *Value1* contained possibly between both *border* rows,
which are "< 'b'" or "> 'c'", will not do any harm, which is not true
in the case of one of other answers.

Note that `df.loc[ind1:ind2]` will get also the row with *ValueA == 'c'*.

Comment: This (and the answer by @aaossa) is fine if it is known a priori that the next-non-NaN value following "b" is "c". If the value "c" is not known in advance, other measures may be required.

Answer (score 0):

Use two masks:

```
# rows after the first b
m1 = df['ValueA'].eq('b').cummax()
# rows after the first c
m2 = df['ValueA'].eq('c').cummax()

# rows between b and c excluded
df[m1&~m2]
```

Another approach, which however will give the rows between the first b/c (included) and b/c (excluded). **This will also work between two b, two c, or if c comes before b!**

```
df[df['ValueA'].isin(('b', 'c')).cumsum().eq(1)]
```

output:

```
  ValueA  ValueB
3      b       4
4    NaN       5
5    NaN       6
```